# Flutter reduce space between widgets

Tags: flutter, user-interface, widget, expansion-tile

I try to display a ExpansionTile with some text in it followed by an Image. Referring to the screenshot you can see that there is some space between both widgets. Does someone know how I can reduce this space?

[image: Screenshot]

```
class Test extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: backGround,
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Aromatics'),
          backgroundColor: appbarColor,
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [
            ExpansionTile(
                iconColor: titleColor,
                title: const Text('Tst', style: TextStyle(color: titleColor)),
                subtitle: const Text('Test subtitle',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
                children: [
                  Container(
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                    child: Column(
                      children: const [
                        Text('Test text',
                            style:
                                TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 13)),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ]),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 1,
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Image.asset('assets/images/test.webp'),
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the `Expanded` widget around the image because it is taking all the remaning space in the `Column` for the image.

Current Code:

```
Column(
    children: [
       ...
       Expanded(
           child: Image.asset('assets/images/test.webp'),
       ),
       ...
    ],
),
```

New Code:

````
Column(
    children: [
       ...
       Image.asset('assets/images/test.webp'),
       ...
    ],
),```
````

Answer (score 2):

As per the [ExpansionTile Doc](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ExpansionTile-class.html), you can use `childrenPadding` to manage the padding for the children widget

> Specifies padding for children.
> If this property is null then ExpansionTileThemeData.childrenPadding is used. If that is also null then the value of childrenPadding is EdgeInsets.zero.

Comment: Solved it, Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Won't removing `Expanded` suit your goals?

```
...
const SizedBox(
  height: 1,
),
Image.asset('assets/images/test.webp'),
...
```